# Loading icon loads in low resolution

Tags: html, css

So I have added a spinning icon that is displayed while something is being loaded on my site, it works so far but it looks really bad and seems like low-res even though the image itself looks nice.

Looks good:

[image: looks good]

This looks bad:

[image: looks bad]

Here is my CSS:

```css
.no-js #loader {
    display: none;
}
.js #loader {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.se-pre-con {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url("../blue_loading.gif") center no-repeat;
}
```

I tried around but couldn't think of why it looks bad. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GIF has a light matte colour applied. As GIFs only have up to 256 colours, and no varying degree of transparency (pixels are either 100% transparent or 100% opaque), image editors can apply a matte colour which translates into pixels in the image which help the edges of opaque pixels "bleed" into the background. However when the matte colour is light and the background is dark, as in your example, the matte pixels are obvious.

You may want to try re-saving the GIF with a darker matte colour, or using CSS animations to create your spinner instead.

Some further reading on transparency:
https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/using/using-transparency-mattes.html

Examples of spinners created using CSS:
https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/